# Distorted SVG Image on <td> in dompdf

Tags: svg, dompdf

I wanted to export a recap data with dompdf, I'm using `loadHTML()` from dompdf, and in the view I'm using `<img src"file.svg">` but the image output is somehow distorted. Here is the the code for the dompdf

**export.php**

```
$reports = $this->getReports($request); extract($request->all());
        $html    = view('pdf/rekap-lp')->with(compact('reports', 'start_date', 'end_date'))->render();

$this->createQRCODE($reports);

$pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$pdf->loadHTML($html);
$pdf->setOptions(['isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true, 'isRemoteEnabled' => true]);

return $pdf->stream(uniqid().'.pdf');
```

Here is the view

```
<tr style="font-size: 13px">
     <td class="text-center">{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
     <td>{{ (ucfirst($item->dugaan_pelanggaran)) ?: '-' }}</td>
     <td class="text-center no-wrap">
         {{ (strftime('%d %B %Y', strtotime($item->tanggal_laporan))) ?: '-' }}
                </td>
     <td>{{ (ucfirst($item->kronologis)) ?: '-' }}</td>
     <td>{{ (ucfirst($item->lokasi)) ?: '-' }}</td>
     <td>{{ (ucfirst($item->satker)) ?: '-' }}</td>
     <td>
        <img src="{{ asset('img/qr-code/lp/' . $item->id_lp .'.svg') }}" >
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the output of my .svg qrcode is like this
[image]

**Update**

I just found out that if I generate the QR Code with a url like `http://localhost/detail/100` the QR Code will be distorted, but if I generate it with a string `This is a very cool website`, the QR Code shown is normal not distorted

Comment: What's in file.svg?

Comment: @RobertLongson QR Code with a URL in it

Comment: What I meant is, please edit the question and add the markup of file.svg.

Answer (score 2):

If possible giving your image an explict height and width will fix this issue.

Dompdf doesn’t seem to handle svgs with auto height and width very well, and doesn’t handle images in tables well either, so the 2 combined is going to be tough for it to render!

If that’s not possible, a couple of savoiurs when working with tables and images on dompdf are:

1. Try adding `style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%"` to your `<table>`.
2. Try adding `style="height:auto; max-width:100%"` to your `<img>` (inside the table), if that’s still not right…
3. Try adding `style="height:auto; max-width:none; width:100%"` to your `<img>` instead.

Normally a combination of 1 with either 2 or 3 will get it rendering correctly.

See https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1448 for a bit of background.

Comment: Already try all of those, but none of it work. Theres an update on my question